# stability and fixed points of $y_{i+1} = 0.5(a_{i+1}/b_{i+1})y_{i} + 0.5(y_{i} + (b_{i+1}-a_{i+1})c)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, control-theory, time-series, stability-theory

I have a data set of a time series, and determined that the data fits this equation, where $y_{n}$ is the dependent variable, $a$ and $b$ are independent variables and $c$ is a constant $y_{i+1} = 0.5(a_{i+1}/b_{i+1})y_{i} + 0.5(y_{i} + (b_{i+1}-a_{i+1})c)$

$a_{n} / b_{n}$ is never greater than 1 and $a_{n} <= b_{n}$

[Edited]
For certain values of a and b it seems like the series oscilates around some value - determined by c, but past some threshold of a/b the series becomes very small.

What is the stability of this equation, specifically what range must a,b,c be in for the equation to stay close to its fixed points. Are there fixed points beyond when

Example values are below:

$c$ may be $500$, $a$ may be $80000$ * $10^{-6}$ and $b$ may range from $80000$ * $10^{-6}$ to $120000$ * $10^{-6}$

Comment: This is just linear first order recurrence equation. Its behavior will depend on the trajectory for $a$ and $b$. You will need to include more information about them in your post.

Comment: @KBS Thanks for the response - what type of information would be useful?

Comment: Everything you have about the system and its parameters.

Comment: A lot of your statements are still inaccurate. You say that "the series oscilates around some value". What value? Or "past some threshold of a/b"? What threshold? Or " the series becomes very small". How small? What is the value? Since your system is time-varying, it may not any fixed point at all, so what do you mean by "to stay close to its fixed points".

Answer (score 1):

The linear recurrence

$$
y_{i+1} = 0.5(a_{i+1}/b_{i+1}+1)y_{i} + 0.5(b_{i+1}-a_{i+1})c
$$

can be easily solved. Calling $u_i = 0.5(a_{i}/b_{i}+1)$ and $v_i = 0.5(b_{i}-a_{i})c$ we follow with

$$
y_i = u_i y_{i-1}+v_i
$$

with solution

$$
y_i = \left(c_0 +\left(\sum _{k=1}^{i} \frac{v_k}{\prod _{j=1}^k u_j}\right)\right)\prod _{j=1}^{i} u_j
$$